# JQuery OnDrag fire a click when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a drag-drop-application which uses JQuery UI onDrag and onDrop. This application is a room reservation system that have tabs. I have made the drop-working perfectly, but there is one functionality I really want (if possible).

Is there a way to create a event-handler for the tabs, that fires only if you are dragging an element?

Example: You want to move a person from Tab1 to Tab2, without clicking the tab, you can only drag the person -> hover the tab -> then the tab gets clicked.

Comment: U can force the click event to fire

Comment: @AntoKing yes, thats what I wanted to happen. I just don't know how.. I have tried the tabs onHover, that fires the onClick that works, but not as intended.. how to make it only fire IF you are dragging an element?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific event handler for dragging an element, but by manipulating other events, you can make it work.

The trick is to use the `mousemove` event, but make it only work when the mouse has been pressed down on the draggable element. Therefore, we make a certain Boolean `true` in the `mousedown` event and then make it `false` in the `mouseup` event. The `mousemove` event checks if the Boolean and runs its code if and only if the Boolean is `true`.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Make draggable draggable
    $("#draggable").draggable();
    //mousedown and mouseup Boolean
    var drragging = false;
    $("#draggable").mousedown(function() { dragging = true; });
    $("#draggable").mouseup(function() { dragging = false; });
    //mousemove event -> mousedrag event
    $("#draggable").mousemove(function() { if (dragging) {
        //The event:
        $("#draggable").css("color", "rgb("+Math.round(255*Math.random())+", "+Math.round(255*Math.random())+", "+Math.round(255*Math.random())+")");
    }});
});
```

```html
<span id="draggable">Drag me!</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very good! I made it work with the onDrag start and stop method to change the "dragging = true/false", thanks for the idea! You are the man